# What is another word for an "insult" when you want to joke or play?

Tags: word-choice

I known that "insult" *(v)* is the way to offend someone.

But, when I only want to make some joke or play with my friends by saying some words that seem to insult them (I don't definitely want to insult them). For example:

A: That girl is very beautiful!!
B: That means all women in your family are ugly, right? You have to think about your new wife! Ha Ha

(B is trying to ..?.. A that A's wife is ugly.)

Which the word in verb is suitable to use?

Comment: Perhaps the title would be clearer if it said something like "Is there a word that means **insult in a friendly or playful manner**?"

Answer (score 10):

I think *tease* is another word which is suitable for insult. Example:

> The children teased the boy because of his stammer.

Answer (score 9):

Finding synonyms for a friendly insult is not easy. But *[josh](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/josh)*, *[rag](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rag%5B3%5D)* and maybe *[gibe](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gibe)* might fit.

Answer (score 4):

B is trying to [tease](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tease) or synonyms thereof.

Answer (score 1):

An older term, largely from African- American culture, is *[doing the dozens](http://www.randomhouse.com/wotd/index.pperl?date=19960903)*, meaning friendly insults.

A more recent term along the same lines is *[signifying](http://www.yourdictionary.com/signifying)*, also primarily used in African-American culture.

Another term used for playful insult is *[trash talk](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trash+talk)*. This is generally less friendly and is mostly used for opponents in sporting activities.

Answer (score 1):

You may find that the word for this is a

> Sarcastic Remark

or just *sarcasm*.  It means when you say something with the intent for it to mean the opposite of the normal meaning.

Like when a friend wins a move in a game, and you exclaim "Oh you're an idiot" when the opposite is meant, given the context:

- you're close friends
- they were very smart (not idiotic) in their skillful move

Answer (score 1):

More of a colloquial term (as I just learned researching it, adopted from professional wrestling), is *ribbing*. Stemming from a *rib*, a practical joke, to *rib [x]* is to tease them in a playful manner.

> B is *ribbing* A about A's wife

Answer (score 0):

A: That girl is very beautiful!!
B: That means all women in your family are ugly, right? You have to think about your new wife! Ha Ha

B is *putting A on* about A's wife.

> [put on](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/put+on): *Slang*. tease or mislead (another)

Alternately, consider *pull someone's leg*.

> [pull someone's leg](http://www.englishclub.com/ref/esl/Idioms/Body/pull_someone_s_leg_687.htm): if you pull someone's leg, you play a joke on them by saying something that isn't true.

Answer (score 0):

A common term I hear for this in the midwest is *jab*.

You could also say that you are *sticking* it to them.

Or *goading* them on.

But the most common of them all is [messing](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=im%20just%20messing) or *playing*.

> Dude, don't get all bent out of shape.  Just messing with you.